# How do I make list of search results editable?

Tags: search, quickfix

There are several times, I need to `grep` for `some_pattern` in some `XHTML` files (many a time, file count in a specified folder goes beyond 10K+).

Previously, I have used [Lugaru's Epsilon Programmer's Editor](http://www.lugaru.com/) and there was `grep` command which invokes the search, and results a list of all matched lines in a `grep-buffer`. Afterwards, a user can use commands (like `keep-matching-lines`, `delete-matching-lines`, `sort-lines`, `uniq` etc.) on the `grep-buffer`. Since, the `grep-buffer` is editable, it is possible to post-process and mold the grep-result to desirable format as required.

But, that was weeks ago! This time, I have started to use Vim as my full-time editor. I am trying to quit all possible habits those are becoming obstacles to learning Vim. So, right now whenever I need to get such a search list, I am trying the same, in following way:

```
:cd d:\test_files\
:cex [] | vimgrep /pattern/ *.xhtml
:cope
```

Now, this servers my purpose well, except that the buffer remains in `RO` mode. So, every time it requires special post-editing process, I need to prepare a replica for the `quickfix-window` and then do as required. The `quickfix-window` is always uneditable.

Is there any way to make the `quickfix-window` editable? I know the result can be post-processed with some other commands in a single line, but I do need to view all the search list as whole and only then can I judge what the next steps should be.

Is there any tweak that can be applied in the `vimrc`? Am I missing something? Pointing out my error or any other approach to get job done, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `:set modifiable`? Alternatively, `:redir` could help.

Comment: @fruglemonkey: Thank you so much....That's what all i needed...you rocks!!!!

Comment: Related post: [Is it possible to grep Vimʼs quickfix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15406138/438329)

Comment: Just got the new updated on Debian with patch: 8.1.0311. Works great! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitively should try the plugin [QFGrep plugin](https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep), which was created after the similar question mentioned in the comments: [Is it possible to grep Vimʼs quickfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406138/is-it-possible-to-grep-vim%ca%bcs-quickfix).

I've been using it for a year and a half, and it works very well. It allows to grep (and reverse grep) the quickfix results, and also allows to restore the original contents. Check plugin homepage, which has [a nice animated gif](https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep).

Comment: mMontu: must give it a try tomorrow....looks like what i really need....

Comment: It is a really cool script...thank you so much...

Answer (score 3):

### New official vim plugin [*cfilter*](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/cfilter/plugin/cfilter.vim)

Since [21.8.2018 (patch: 8.1.0311)](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8c5e0093c9badced73e382915fb024a5c3ea463b) the plugin *cfilter* is distributed with vim in `$VIMRUNTIME`. It is documented under `:h cfilter-plugin`.

Load plugin *cfilter* when needed or load it always in your vimrc

```
:packadd cfilter
```

Filter quickfix list with

```
:Cfilter DPUST
```