# Using global command on Quickfix entries

Tags: replace, quickfix, global-command

I find and replace a pattern in all the files in my project (which is a big one). After the search is done, quickfix window is opened with the matches. The matches are in different files in different directories/sub-directories.

When I want to replace all the matches in the quickfix list, I run the following command:

```
:cfdo %s/old/new/g
```

Sometimes I want to replace only the matches in files that are in a specific directory (e.g., `DPUST`) and don't touch the matches in the files in the other directories.

I tried running the following command while the cursor is in quickfix window:

```
:g/DPUST/cfdo %s/old/new/gc
```

But I found that this tries to replace the matches in every quickfix entry.

What am I missing to get this to work?

Comment: I guess you populate your quickfix list with a `grep` command or something similar. Wouldn't it be easier to restrict this `grep` command to the directory you want to modify instead of trying to bend `:cfdo`?

Comment: I use `ripgrep` for searching. I want to search all the project files. Only based on the search result, I can decide in which directory should I replace the matches.

Comment: When you read [`:h :cfdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3acfdo) you see that `cfdo` actually uses `:cfirst`, `{cmd}`, `:cnfile`, `{cmd}`, etc so calling `cfdo` in a global command is useless, and I don't think you have a way to filter the entries of the quickfix list. I think your best bet is to use a second call to `ripgrep` to restrict to the directory you want to treat. Let's see if someone come up with a better solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update: New official vim plugin [*cfilter*](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/cfilter/plugin/cfilter.vim)

Since [21.8.2018 (patch: 8.1.0311)](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8c5e0093c9badced73e382915fb024a5c3ea463b) the plugin *cfilter* is distributed with vim in `$VIMRUNTIME`. It is documented under [`:h cfilter-plugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#cfilter-plugin).

Load plugin *cfilter* when needed or load it always in your vimrc

```
:packadd cfilter
```

Using abbreviations in case of a vanilla vim this can be as short as `:pa c<tab><cr>`.

Filter quickfix list with

```
:Cfilter DPUST
```

Again, using abbreviations in case of vanilla vim the command `:Cfilter` can be shortened to `:Cf`.

Run `:cfdo`

```
:cfdo %s/old/new/g
```

---

**Original Answer**

As far as I see it, `:cfdo` works on the quickfix list. This will not be changed by prefixing the command with `:g/DPUST/`. You could have come up with `:v/DPUST/delete` and then `:cfdo %s/old/new/gc`. However, the quickfix list cannot be changed easily. There are quite a few plugins which provide support for this

- [vim-lister](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-lister) `:Qfilter DPUST`
- [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) `:Keep DPUST`
- [QFGrep](https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep) `:QFGrepPat DPUST`

Following plugins allow to remove lines from the quickfix list with vim commands e.g. `:v/DPUST/d`

- [quickfix-reflector](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim)
- [vim-qfedit](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-qfedit)

If do not want a full plugin, add following  lines to your vimrc to get the command `:Qfilter`

```
" From https://github.com/dhruvasagar/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/plugin/filter_list.vim
function! s:FilterList(list, bang, pattern)
  let list = deepcopy(a:list)
  let [cmp, and_or] = a:bang ? ['!~#', '&&'] : ['=~#', '||']
  return filter(a:list, "bufname(v:val.bufnr) " . cmp . " a:pattern " . and_or . " v:val.text " . cmp . " a:pattern")
endfunction
function! s:FilterQuickfixList(bang, pattern)
  call setqflist(s:FilterList(getqflist(), a:bang, a:pattern))
endfunction
command! -bang -nargs=1 -complete=file Qfilter call s:FilterQuickfixList(<bang>0, <q-args>)
```

This has already been asked:

- [Is it possible to grep Vim's quickfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15406138/is-it-possible-to-grep-vims-quickfix)
- [How do I make list of search results editable?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/how-do-i-make-list-of-search-results-editable)
- [Quickfix list, how to add and remove entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42905008/quickfix-list-how-to-add-and-remove-entries)

Note `grep` stands for `global/regular expression/print`. Questions using the term `grep` or `global` are referring possibly to identical tasks.

Comment: @update of the question: I do not see your point here. It is actually helpful. As it has been pointed out `:cfdo` operates on the quickfix list which means there is not much you can do: except not using `:cfdo`, creating the quickfix list correctly in the first place, or adjusting it to your need. BTW vim-qf allows you to restore the list after you have changed it. This means you do not need to re-run your search if you decide to run `:cfdo` on a different folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the quickfix list to decide what directory you want to use/exclude why do you not just execute another search just before the `:cfdo`? Like this:

1. first you search `:RIPGREP search-term`
2. look at the result and decide what to include
3. rerun the last command with some explicit directory <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>`some-dir`
4. then run your replace command: `:cfdo %s/foo/bar/gc`

If your custom `:RIPGREP` command supports command chaining you can type 3 and 4 on one line and if you use this really often you can try to turn it into a custom command (retrieve the last command from history with `histget()`).