# Pipe :Ag output to a new buffer

Tags: regular-expression, buffers

I'd like to search for a regex using `Ag`. This results in more than 1000 findings. I'd like to save these findings in a buffer to be able to go through them slowly

Comment: To me this is a duplicate of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8378/1841)

Comment: @statox could be. We also have a Q somewhere about filtering the quickfix list (https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6511/10604, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `:h fzf-examples`:

```
" An action can be a reference to a function that processes selected lines
function! s:build_quickfix_list(lines)
  call setqflist(map(copy(a:lines), '{ "filename": v:val }'))
  copen
  cc
endfunction

let g:fzf_action = {
  \ 'ctrl-q': function('s:build_quickfix_list'),
  \ 'ctrl-t': 'tab split',
  \ 'ctrl-x': 'split',
  \ 'ctrl-v': 'vsplit' }

let $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS = '--bind ctrl-a:select-all'
```

Having this you can select all candidates with `ctrl-a` and press `ctrl-q` to put them into quickfix. And if needed copy/paste lines from there to a new buffer.

[image]

PS, I have actually tried to directly populate a new buffer but couldn't do it.
Filled an issue to clarify this https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2164

PPS, found in source code that for grep-like fzf (grep, ag, rg) selected multiple lines are put into quickfix. So you don't need to provide `ctrl-q` to `g:fzf_action` just `$FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS` to select all candidates then select and press `Enter`.